# Is there a way to retain an HTTP GET parameter in Sinatra without manually writing them in the links?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I've got a simple sinatra webpage, with multiple color schemes.
To change a color scheme i simply use a simple get parameter in the following way:

```
before do
  color = params[:color]
  if color == 'blue'
    @color = :blue
  elsif color == 'pink'
    @color = :pink
  else
    @color = :orange
  end
end
```

But when the user clicks a link on the website, the color parameter (of course) disappears.
Is there a way of keeping the color parameter without doing the following? (In haml):

```
%a{:href => "/?color=#{@color.to_s}"} Home
```

Comment: A cookie would probably be more appropriate for this.

Comment: Yes, but I was trying to do it in a more RESTful way

Comment: Why exactly do you think using a cookie would not be RESTful? Would you really want a color scheme to be forced upon another user when one user shares a link to your site?

Comment: RESTful sometimes doesn't mean better, I guess.

Comment: @Andrew As far as I know REST is about keeping the state in the calls, and thus a cookie would represent a state outside the REST call thus making it not RESTful.

Comment: @floatless yes maybe I just have to go to use the old way using session/cookie

Comment: So if a user logged in you'd argue that the session ID should be a GET parameter? There's a reason no one does that anymore. Further, the color of the page is not in any way tied to the resource being requested, so it really isn't part of RESTful request at all.

Comment: @Andrew maybe I chose the wrong wording, but I was just curious if it were possible like some other frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a new HAML helper (like in [that repository](https://github.com/sbfaulkner/sinatra-helpers)) and use it in your template like any other helpers. I think it is the most convenient way to achieve that.